# How to make liferay supports EL in jsp?

Tags: jsp, liferay, el, liferay-6

I'm learning liferay and using liferay 6.0.6, I wrote some el to fetch the value of pojo, but nothing was populated. why is that? I tried to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` on the top of jsp but no effect. Strangely I can use EL in another sample code, product registration from Liferay In Action, a liferay book. I copied the same `init.jsp` to my current portlet, but not worked.

init.jsp

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/security" prefix="liferay-security" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
```

Comment: can u provide some code how you are using EL to fetch data?

Comment: If the EL is working with another code and not your code then there sure is some problem with your code. Can you paste how you are using ELs in portlet?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use EL in Liferay (I personally prefer EL to scriptlets as scriptlets are generally considered bad practice).
Drop these jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder of your portlet project:
[jstl-1.1.2.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.1.2) and [standard-1.1.2.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard/1.1.2). After this you can use Expression Language, as well as JSTL core tags:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```